# Is it possible for the server to send messages to Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, subscriber, polling

Let's say I have a component c:Widget which is being displayed in some user's browser.  c:Widget displays the contents a Widget__c record.

Let's say something causes the Widget__c record to update on the server.

Is it possible for the server to send a message to c:Widget, which I might be able to handle as an event?

In the less favourable alternative, is it possible to create a background process in c:Widget which will periodically poll the Widget__c record for updates?

Comment: you should read platform event. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/platform_events_basics

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-platform-events/steps/platform-event-subscribe

Comment: maybe [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm)?

Comment: Forgot about platform events (I actually read about that a few months ago, but haven't done anything with them)... Doesn't look like SFDC handles them on the lightning side with the same ease as Application or Component events though.  :-/  ... But I could probably do something with this.  :-)

Comment: You can create a `PushTopic` to that widget and subscribe in your component, no? They even did that in a demo at DF17 if memory serves.

Answer (score 0):

You've to return the data or some kind of indicator from the server, which can be handled in lightning component controller and display message accordingly.